# Data stored in warp Session does not persist

Tags: session, rust, rust-warp

I am trying to set up a server backend as an exercise.

I want to store some data in `warp_sessions::MemoryStore` but I cannot achieve it. I base on the `warp_sessions/examples/shared_mutable_session` example.

I can get the data written into the session. I can read it back immediately after I write into it (variables `_a` and `_b` in the code below), but they don't persist between the calls. The variables `_a_pre` and `_b_pre` return empty string on the consecutive handler calls.

Now the questions:

- What am I doing wrong?
- if I want to use the same session for different routes and I pass the `session_store.clone()` in the filter, like it is done in warp example - will the modifications of the session be stored? For now I don't use the cloned instance of the store but the data is lost anyway. I do however need the data to be used by different routes
- In the docs  of warp_sessions it is said that MemoryStore should not be used in production. What should be used in production instead?

My route handler function looks like this:

```
pub async fn verify_handler(body: warp::hyper::body::Bytes, mut session_with_store:SessionWithStore<MemoryStore> ) -> Result<(Html<String>, SessionWithStore<MemoryStore>), Rejection>  {

  session_with_store.cookie_options = warp_sessions::CookieOptions {
    cookie_name: "siwe_minimal",
    cookie_value: None,
    max_age:Some(3600),
    domain: None,
    path: None,
    secure: true,
    http_only: true,
    same_site: Some(SameSiteCookieOption::Strict),
  };
  
  let shared_session = Arc::new(RwLock::new(session_with_store.session));
 
  let _a_pre: String = shared_session
      .read()
      .unwrap()
      .get("nonce")  
      ..unwrap_or_default();

  shared_session
      .write()
      .unwrap()
      .insert("nonce", nonce )   
      .unwrap();
    
  let _a: String = shared_session
      .read()
      .unwrap()
      .get("nonce")  
      .unwrap();

  let msgstr = message.to_string();

  let _b_pre: String = shared_session
  .read()
  .unwrap()
  .get("siwe")  
  .unwrap_or_default(); 

  shared_session
      .write()
      .unwrap()
      .insert("siwe", msgstr)  
      .unwrap();

       
  let _b: String = shared_session
  .read()
  .unwrap()
  .get("siwe")  
  .unwrap();

   
  session_with_store.session = Arc::try_unwrap(shared_session)
      .unwrap()
      .into_inner()
      .unwrap(); 


  Ok::<_, Rejection>(
    (
      warp::reply::html("req".to_string()),
      session_with_store
    )
  )

}
```

the route is defined like this (if it matters):

```
let session_store = MemoryStore::new();
let verify_route 
    = warp::path("verify")
    .and(warp::post())
    .and(warp::body::bytes())
    .and(warp_sessions::request::with_session(session_store, None))
    .and_then( verify_handler)
    .untuple_one()
    .and_then(warp_sessions::reply::with_session)
    .recover(handle_rejection)
    .with(&cors);
```

Comment: I don't think the example really justifies itself, it looks to be an example demonstrating a way to make the session into a shared mutable reference inside your handler if you need that. But you just want to modify the session so simply... do that. All the sharing stuff is unnecessary.

Comment: And so is keeping on locking and unlocking the RWLock incidentally, you want to mutate the object so just `write()` the object once, keep a reference to the lock guard and do all your reading from and writing to that, then drop it once you're done with the session to zip it back up.

Comment: "In the docs of warp_sessions it is said that MemoryStore should not be used in production. What should be used in production instead?" probably your own [`SessionStore`](https://docs.rs/warp-sessions/latest/warp_sessions/trait.SessionStore.html) implementation based on some sort of persistent storage e.g. filesystem, database, ...

Comment: Actually `MemorySession` and `SessionStore` are just re-exports from [`async-session`](https://github.com/http-rs/async-session), and their readme [lists a few backends](https://github.com/http-rs/async-session#available-session-stores), though surprisingly nothing FS-based. Also from the issues some backends are apparently dead.

Comment: hmm. i dont know - this is the only example in the repo that creates the cookie. My rust is not strong enough with me to question dev provided examples that much. I rather learn from them. I will try to simplify the write procedure.

Comment: Nitpick: `.unwrap_or_else(|| "".to_string())` is the same as `.unwrap_or_default()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting the CookieOptions in the route definition to None, meaning that the warp_sessions code will expect a cookie named `sid` to get the session ID. Link to code showing this behavior:

https://github.com/ajpauwels/warp-sessions/blob/c440817f41c331cfa21a0c3a995be20ab420bb5e/src/request.rs#L17

However, in the route handler, you override the cookie_options to a different value, with a cookie name of `siwe_minimal`. This means that, during the reply portion of the warp_sessions logic, the cookie containing the session ID that will persist your session across calls will be named something different than what the route definition expects.

Link to where Set-Cookie header is defined in the warp_sessions reply code: https://github.com/ajpauwels/warp-sessions/blob/c440817f41c331cfa21a0c3a995be20ab420bb5e/src/session.rs#L98

Link to `to_string` definition of CookieOptions which shows how `cookie_name` is used: https://github.com/ajpauwels/warp-sessions/blob/c440817f41c331cfa21a0c3a995be20ab420bb5e/src/cookie.rs#L24

In order to solve this, I would suggest either:

1. Instead of setting CookieOptions to `None` in your route definition, set your options there
2. Keeping `None` in the route definition, and removing the options override in the route handler entirely

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the issue! Working code at https://github.com/chris-the-wiz/siwe_minimal_rust/